# Having complications with my tile map not showing up on my device

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a tile map and when I run it on my simulator, it shows up fine. When I run it on my iPhone and go to the map, nothing shows up, only a black screen. any ideas on what is happening?

```
   @interface LevelDesertOne : CCLayer {
    CCTMXTiledMap *desertMap;
    CCTMXLayer *bgLayerDesert;
    }
    @property(nonatomic, retain) CCTMXTiledMap @desertMap;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) CCTMXLayer *bgLayerDesert;
    +(CCScene *) scene;
    @end

@implementation LevelDesertOne
    @synthesize desertMap;
    @synthesize bgLevelDesert;
    +(CCScene *) scene{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    LevelDesertOne *layer = [LevelDesertOne node];
    [scene addChild: layer];
    return scene;
    }
    -(id) init{
    if( (self=[superinit]) ){
    self.desertMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"Desert.tmx"];
    self.bgLayerDesert = [desertMap layerNamed:@"bgDesert"];
    [self addChild:desertMap z:-1];
    }
    return self;
    }
    @end
```

Comment: Can we see how you are adding the tilemap to your scene?

Comment: @PWiggin here's the code

Comment: how big is your tilemap (in tiles) and how many layers? Cocos2D has a draw limit of 16,384 tiles at most (128x128 tiles, single layer), at least on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and paste, please don't ad-lib. Your interface and implementation names do not match, synthesize statement for non-matching objects, etc. My *guess* is that your `tmx` file has different casing, and you've made a typo. In the simulator, it wouldn't matter if your file is actually named Desert.tmx . You could call it DeSeRt.TmX and it would still run, but on the actual device it would not. Default for OSX is case-insensitive filesystem, default for iOS is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your tile map is added to the project and being copied into the resources folder.  Assuming that this is the case, it may also be that the file you are loading `@"Desert.tmx"` is a different upper/lowercase than the actual file you're linking.  (MacOS filesystem is by default not case sensitive, iOS filesystem is)